# Dynamic listview to Details view page in Jquery mobile

Tags: android, cordova, listview, jquery-mobile

I have manage to create an Dynamic listview in Json but I want to do details view when I click that listview in Jquery mobile,When I click that Dynamic list I want to get more details about that list.

Jquery code

```
<script>
            $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
                      function(data)
                      {
                      $("#images").empty();

                      $(data.items).each(function(i,item)
                            {
                             $("#images").append(movielist(item));
                             //if ( i == 4 ) return false;
                             });

                      $("#images").listview("refresh");

                      });

                      function movielist(item)
                      {

                          return "<li><a href='#pageone2'>"+item.title+"</a></li>";
                      }
            </script>

    </head>
```

Html Code :

```
<body>  
         //Page 1
        <div data-role="page" id="pageone" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="header">
                <div class="custom_header">
                    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="custom_main">
                    <p style="color:white">Welcome!</p>
                    <div data-role="content">
                 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="images" >
                     </ul>
                 </div>
                    <br> <br>     
                    <a href="#pageone2" data-transition="flip" data-role="button">Go</a>
                </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <div class="custom_footer">
                    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** to add a click handler on dynamically created dom elements:

```
$("#images").on("click", "li a", function(e){
    //code to show details goes here
});
```

UPDATE:

You could save the object details in the listitem as a data attribute:

```
  $("#images").empty(); 
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      $("#images").append("<li><a data-details='" + JSON.stringify(data[i]) + "' href='#pageone2'>"+data[i].Name+"</a></li>");
  };
  $("#images").listview("refresh");
```

Then on click, retrive the data attribute and write the values to the details page, e.g.:

```
$("#images").on("click", "li a", function(e){
    var obj = $(this).data("details");

    $("#theDetails").empty();
    $("#theDetails").append("<p>Name: " + obj.Name +  "</p>");
    $("#theDetails").append("<p>id: " + obj.id +  "</p>");
    $("#theDetails").append("<p>Email: " + obj.Email +  "</p>");
    $("#theDetails").append("<p>Designation: " + obj.Designation +  "</p>");
    $("#theDetails").append("<p>ContactNo: " + obj.ContactNo +  "</p>");
    $("#theDetails").append("<p>Address: " + obj.Address +  "</p>");
});
```

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/wWVvpo)**

Comment: Example If I have 7 Properties in one object , I will show only one property in listview example name property, the remaining I want to show in details view  {
        Address = "United Kingdom";
        ContactNo = 9988112345;
        Designation = SenioriOSdeveloper;
        Email = "thiru@gmail.com";
        Name = Abdul;
        id = 1;
       }

Comment: @VyTcdc, I have updated the answer and provided a working CodePen demo. You would need to customize the details view to your liking...

Comment: Thanks a lot It is Working.